# Ubuntu 20.04 Mysql8 keep accepting null/any password for root

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-20.04

After installing "mysql-server" on ubuntu20 and running "mysql_secure_installation" and setting a password the system still not authenticating correctly and still accepting any/blank password for mysql root user via linux root user while from other linux users its not accepting any.

Comment: Just read everything about the new mysql auth plugins. Sorted now.

Comment: Provide an Answer so others can benefit.  (And you will get rep points for it.)

Answer (score 0):

So basically by default Mysql now (on most distributions like Ubuntu/Debian) is using "caching_sha2_password" plugin for user authentication and "auth_socket" plugin for 'root' user. Previously it used to use "mysql_native_password".

"auth_socket" plugin does not require to set any password instead it uses the operating system credentials and pick the operating system logged-in username and authenticate the connecting user as the Mysql account that has the same user name i-e root -> root. So you dont need to any password for mysql root user.

You can execute following commands to check/change current auth plugin for a user.

```
select User,Host,Plugin from mysql.user;
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'xxxx';
```